# Step serie for navigator

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to use "step" in the navigator serie? As documented in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series) it should be possible, but for some reason is not working for me.

I'm making a "Gantt" chart with Highstock, and I don't like the default navigator behavior for charts with multiple panes (by default the navigator "borrow" the first serie data). That's why I'm supplying the navigator series data

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Teles/wcm17cbf/)

```
$(function () {

    var data1 = [[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, null, null], [3, 0, 1], [5, 0, 1], [5, null, null], [6, 0, 1], [10, 0, 1]]
    var data2 = [[1, null, null], [2, 0, 1], [4, 0, 1], [10, null, null]]
    var dataNavigator = [[1, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [5, 0], [6, 1], [10, 1]]

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
            type: 'arearange'
        },

        xAxis : {
            ordinal: false
        },

        navigator : {
            series : {
                step: true,
                data: dataNavigator
            }
        },

        yAxis: [{
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: false,
            height: '50%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2,
            labels: {enabled: false},
            title : {
                text: "y0"
            }
        }, {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: false,
            top: '50%',
            height: '50%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2,
            labels: {enabled: false},
            title : {
                text: "y1"
            }
        }],

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 2
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Temperature variation by day'
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}<br/>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Serie Name 1',
            data: data1,
            step: true,
            yAxis: 0
        }, {
            name: 'Serie Name 2',
            data: data2,
            step: true,
            yAxis: 1,
            id: 'series1'
        }]

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `step` is defined for series of type `line` you have to manually define it. Also, the values for `step` are `'left'`, `'right'` and `'center'`. For example:

```
navigator : {
    series : {
        type: 'line',
        step: 'left',
        data: dataNavigator
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wcm17cbf/1/) of how it looks.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution =)

Comment: I have used step in other charts, but i didn't set the type of the series and it works anyway. Only the navigator require to define the type to line?

Comment: The default type is `line` if nothing is specified in the series or chart options. I guess this might not hold for the navigator series, or that it uses it from the first (borrowed) series, which would also not be `line`.